# Android XML Linear Layout Display

Tags: android, layout, display

Good morning guys,

I am having a bit of trouble resolving an issue and could use some help. I created an XML resource file called comment__layout. For some reason I cannot get the layout to display full screen. Please can you review the XML code and help. As you will see in the screenshot the Comment layout is loaded over the parent layout which is exactly what I want however, I would like the Comment layout to be full screen.

[image: screenshot of image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/comment__layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_heading__layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Comments"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gps_orange"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/comment_close__button"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="X"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comments_add_comment__layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment_add__edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/comment_add__button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+Add"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/comments_text_views__scroll_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/comments_text_views__layout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

PARENT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/component_wizard_layout_parent__relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/component_wizard_layout_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_component_wizard_manager"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/component_wizard_component_popup__layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean ?
Your `comment__layout` is already set to be shown on Full Screen as its height is set as `match_parent` !!

Comment: Please post your java code from where you are inflating comment__layout.xml.

Comment: show your parent layout xml as well on which you are showing your comment layout.

Comment: I cannot add the Java code. It may be above your level of understanding. I am not using native android and I have written my own component system which basically replaces the android `View` and dynamically builds the GUI based on data contained within a data carrier. I have included the parent XML

Comment: *It may be above your level of understanding.*, then you shouldn't ask the question here.

Comment: Then where else should I ask? Is that not what this community is for? This has absolutely nothing to do with the Java code. So you want me to post the libs I have written which is about 90k lines of code as this is what builds the components? It makes no sense. Every element is set to match_parent. This is why I asked but obviously this is a community of beginners and retards.